# Problem regarding diffraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, diffraction

In the case of single slit diffraction, is it necessary that the distance between slits must be less or equal than the wavelength of light in order to calculate angular width of dark fringes?

I got this question from my text book.It said:

if the distance between edges of a single slit diffraction  is 0.1mm and the wavelength of light is 5500 *10^(-10)m. Determine the angular width of central maxima.If not possible,explain why?

The answer said it was not possible.

Please help me on this problem.

Comment: "... distance between slits ..." But you said that this was about *single* slit diffraction! If the question is trying to say that the distance between the *edges* of a slit is 0.1 mm, then it's perfectly possible to calculate the angular width of the central maximum.

Comment: Sorry for a slight mistake.Actually,I meant distance between edges in a single slit diffraction.

Comment: Yes that's what I guessed. See comment based on this guess.

Comment: Try the calculator here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/sinslit.html#c1